# Building OpenCV 3.3 using Mingw-make gives error 2 at 47%

Tags: c++, opencv, build, cmake, mingw

When trying to build OpenCV 3.3.0 with the mingw compiler I keep getting an error. First I am using CMake to generate the build files (I choose Mingw makefiles and select the gcc en g++ compilers myself, although using the native compilers gives me the same error at the exact same time). When I then use mingw32-make to build OpenCV I get the following error around 48%:

```
 48%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/mathfuncs_core.avx.cpp.obj
[ 48%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/convert.avx2.cpp.obj
[ 48%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/mathfuncs_core.avx2.cpp.obj
[ 48%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/stat.avx2.cpp.obj
[ 48%] Building RC object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\windres.exe: unknown option -- W
Usage: C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\windres.exe [option(s)] [input-file] [output-file]
 The options are:
  -i --input=<file>            Name input file
  -o --output=<file>           Name output file
  -J --input-format=<format>   Specify input format
  -O --output-format=<format>  Specify output format
  -F --target=<target>         Specify COFF target
     --preprocessor=<program>  Program to use to preprocess rc file
     --preprocessor-arg=<arg>  Additional preprocessor argument
  -I --include-dir=<dir>       Include directory when preprocessing rc file
  -D --define <sym>[=<val>]    Define SYM when preprocessing rc file
  -U --undefine <sym>          Undefine SYM when preprocessing rc file
  -v --verbose                 Verbose - tells you what it's doing
  -c --codepage=<codepage>     Specify default codepage
  -l --language=<val>          Set language when reading rc file
     --use-temp-file           Use a temporary file instead of popen to read
                               the preprocessor output
     --no-use-temp-file        Use popen (default)
  -r                           Ignored for compatibility with rc
  @<file>                      Read options from <file>
  -h --help                    Print this help message
  -V --version                 Print version information
FORMAT is one of rc, res, or coff, and is deduced from the file name
extension if not specified.  A single file name is an input file.
No input-file is stdin, default rc.  No output-file is stdout, default rc.
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\windres.exe: supported targets: pe-i386 pei-i386 elf32-i386 elf32-little elf32-big plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:1641: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1550: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am quite the novice when it comes to building a library and for some reason building them always seems to fail with me. Can anyone help me?

-
Martijn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [this answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/168538/building-opencv-with-mingw-gcc-710-and-cmake-390-windresexe-unknown-option-w/) can help. Its a problem with cmake and precompiled headers

> try this : in cmake uncheck ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS

Comment: Could you actually elaborate on what the answer in the link says, to prevent the risk of the link going bad?

Comment: This works! Unfortunately I faced another issue later on in the proces, but that would be off topic ofcourse. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If unchecking `ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS` doesn't work. Try this:

1. Add a new entry to CMake
2. Name the entry: `OPENCV_ALLOCATOR_STATS_COUNTER_TYPE` with `Value(String): int64_t`
3. Configure and generate the `MAKEFILE`
4. Go to the build directory and execute `make install` or `mingw32-make install`

If you want more info of your compilation log, you can run `make install VERBOSE=1`